# Product filter in Ajax will work in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have this code in Ajax but I want this to work in Wordpress. I just want to make a product filter in Ajax that will work in WordPress. I am just new to this. Any help and idea please?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   filter_data();

   function filter_data()
   {
       $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
       var action = 'fetch_data';
       var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
       var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
       var brand = get_filter('brand');
       var ram = get_filter('ram');
       var storage = get_filter('storage');
       $.ajax({
           url:"fetch_data.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, ram:ram, storage:storage},
           success:function(data){
               $('.filter_data').html(data);
           }
       });
   }

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_action', 'filter_data' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_action', 'filter_data' );

   function get_filter(class_name)
   {
       var filter = [];
       $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
           filter.push($(this).val());
       });
       return filter;
   }

   $('.common_selector').click(function(){
       filter_data();
   });

   $('#price_range').slider({
       range:true,
       min:1000,
       max:65000,
       values:[1000, 65000],
       step:500,
       stop:function(event, ui)
       {
           $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
           $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
           $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
           filter_data();
       }
   });

});
</script>
```

How can I make an ajax call in wordpress without use of plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function filter_data(){

   $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
   var action = 'fetch_data';
   var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
   var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
   var brand = get_filter('brand');
   var ram = get_filter('ram');
   var storage = get_filter('storage');
  var data = {
              action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, 
              maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, ram:ram, 
              storage:storage
          };

      $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',data,function(response){
          $('.filter_data').html(data);
      });
  }
</script>
```

In you function.php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_data','filter_data');   // for loggedin user

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_data', 'filter_data'); // for non loggedin user

 function filter_data()
   {

      $minimum_price = $_POST['minimum_price'];
      $maximum_price = $_POST['maximum_price'];
      $brand= $_POST['brand'];
      $ram= $_POST['ram'];
      $storage= $_POST['storage'];

      // here your product filter code
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Jasmeen for the help. Sorry i am new in wordpress. I added the fetch_data.php at product filter code still i didn't get the output.